# JFrog - running update command prepends semicolon to property name in Artifactory when updating property

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

When downloading the latest version of jfrog.exe from "https://jfrog.com/getcli/" (the windows exe), running jfrog to update an artifactory value fails.

The command I am running is this:

```
jfrog rt sp "test-local/test.dat" Build=828
```

When I run it, a property called ';Build' is created, with a value of 828. The intended property

I have a previous version of the exe (that a colleague happened to have) works just fine. An existing property called 'Build' is updated just fine (or created if it doesn't exist). I also downloaded a previous version of the exe from their site from October that worked fine as well.

Our company presently doesn't have support w/ jfrog right now (we are trying to get it back), but I wanted to throw this out there and see if anyone agrees this seems like a bug.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I've just given it a try with Artifactroy version 5.8.1, JFrog CLI version 1.13.1, and it seems to work as it should. The value of the property is changed and I can't see any new property with ;. 
The key of the property is unchanged. The only thing that is different is that I'm using MAC and you are using Win. (Which can be a factor)

Comment: I've just tried it on a Windows machine, with JFrog CLI 1.13.1. It works well for me. Could ut be that you're using an older version of JFrog CLI?